# Monitor File for New Lines and Write to File

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script that monitors a file for new lines and then potentially writes that new line to a different file if it passes a certain condition. This script needs to run continuously to monitor the file and constantly pipe these lines to the condition. I have been using 
`tail -f filename.txt` to monitor the file for growth, but I am unsuccessful in the latter two parts. Is this possible to do?

Comment: You should add more detail. What are the conditions?

Comment: Have you considered, directly processing the output of the process that created the file.

Comment: What have you tried in the latter two parts (you say that you were unsuccessful)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complicated your input to output is going to be you could use a script that handles each line like this:

`tail -f 'filename' | xargs -L1 'script'`

'script' would then be executed for each line with the line as arguments to it(accessed by "$@" in the script).

Rich in the comments suggested using `grep` or `sed` in the following way:

`tail -f 'filename' | grep -e 'expr1' -e 'expr2' >> 'newfile'`

or

`tail -f 'filename' | sed 's/Conditions for line./Line that goes to new file./g' >>'newfile'`

Comment: Could be simpler: `tail -F filename|grep -e expr1 -e expr2>>output`

Comment: True, depends on what the poster needs it to do. I understood it to need more processing, but I added grep and sed options.

Comment: Thanks for incorporating my suggestion! I didn't draw attention to it, but I'm actually saying `-F`, which follows a file _path_ which may be absent when `tail` is run, or become absent, or be replaced. Seems a better strategy for arbitrary stuff like this. I like your `sed` option - and sure, we could imagine all sorts of others like a `perl` or `awk` or ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯